# Can I receive emails with my desktop application

Tags: c#, email

I have a winform C# desktop app.  At the moment I call a web service on my own server to check for messages.

A idea occurred to me (it maybe a bad idea!) that instead of polling my web services I somehow mange to send my desktop app a email form my server (bypassing any other email clients on that PC).

Is this possible? Like I said it maybe a bad idea.

Comment: You can use IMAP to check a mail server.

Comment: @SLaks Hi, thanks for replying.  I shall take a look at this and comment back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can!

Outlook (and those other clients) are only desktop applications themselves.

You're probably better accessing those emails via the server than a webservice anyway..

Try http://www.joshwright.com/tips/sending-receiving-email-in-csharp

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  I shall take a look at this and comment back

Comment: That was a good link.